# cannot initiate expo bare workflow with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I`m trying to initiate expo bare workflow with typescirpt.

But after I type "expo init [project name]" in command window,

I cannot find minimal(typescirpt) option.

```
? Choose a template: » - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
    ----- Managed workflow -----
    blank               a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
    blank (TypeScript)  same as blank but with TypeScript configuration
    tabs (TypeScript)   several example screens and tabs using react-navigation and TypeScript
    ----- Bare workflow -----
>   minimal             bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started
```

Dose anyone know solution?

Answer (score 21):

#### *** Update January 2023 ***

##### Option 1

1. Initialize the project with `npx create-expo-app` command.
2. Create a `tsconfig.json` in your project root with `touch tsconfig.json`.
3. Rename `App.js` to `App.tsx` with `mv App.js App.tsx`.
4. Run `yarn start` or `npm run start`. It will prompt you to install the required dependencies (typescript, @types/react, @types/react-native), and automatically configure your `tsconfig.json`.
5. Switch to the "bare" workflow with `npx expo eject` command.

For more info see the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/) on Expo Typescript support.

##### Option 2

Initialize the project with `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript` command.

For more info see the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript) on React Native Typescript support.

##### Option 3

Use the template with one command `npx create-expo-app -t expo-ts`.

For more info please read [Starting React Native Project in 2023](https://dev.to/vladimirvovk/starting-react-native-project-in-2023-2le) article.

#### *** Original Answer February 2022 ***

##### Option 1

1. Initialize the project with `expo init` command and choose `minimal` as a template. Or use this command: `expo init --template bare-minimum --name <your-app-name>`.
2. Create a `tsconfig.json` in your project root: `touch tsconfig.json`.
3. Rename `App.js` to `App.tsx`: `mv App.js App.tsx`.
4. Run `expo start`. It will prompt you to install the required dependencies (typescript, @types/react, @types/react-native), and automatically configure your `tsconfig.json`.

For more info see the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/typescript/) on Expo Typescript support.

##### Option 2

Use the template with one command `expo init --template @vladimir-vovk/expo-bare-typescript`.

For more info please read [Starting React Native Project in 2022](https://dev.to/vladimirvovk/starting-a-react-native-project-in-2022-31m7) article.

!! Unfortunately, `expo-template-bare-typescript` package is outdated. It will install Expo 41.

Answer (score 5):

**+ 4.62.0**:   **there is no longer the option to create a Bare Workflow project with Typescript already configured.**

*So:*

1. run: `expo init nome-do-seu-app`
2. Choose: `Bare Workflow -> Minimal`
3. Create a `tsconfig.json` in your project root
4. Run `expo start`. It will prompt you to install the required
   dependencies (typescript, @types/react, @types/react-native), and
   automatically configure your tsconfig.json.

[image]

5. Open the tsconfig.json and add `"strict": true`

[image]

6. Rename App.js to App.tsx: mv App.js App.tsx.

Finish

Now your project Bare Workflow is with Typescript configured!

Answer (score 2):

Im with this issue to, but you can initiate your project by running

```sh
 expo init --template expo-template-bare-typescript --name appname
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `expo-template-bare-typescript` package is outdated. It will install Expo 41.